# Pig: Absolute value of an integer

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to give back the absolute value of an integer field but does not work. 
How i can do it correctly?

```
y = foreach x generate
        ABS(quantity);
```

thanks

Comment: IntABs() works thanks

Answer (score 1):

IntAbs is the solution that works for integer also not only for expressions

Comment: please do not add comments as answers. You will need to get certain reputations (I think its 50) so you can comment. 
Anyways, to answer your question, certain Pig functions work only on variables/relations and not on expressions. So you need to evaluate the value of the expression in 1 statement and then use the value to pass it to IntAbs() function in second statements.
I hope it helps.